# Is it possible to charge users using PayPal API without redirecting them to a checkout page?

Tags: e-commerce, paypal

### Post Question Edit:

I found out that it is possible by using the [Preapproval API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/preapproval-api-operation) + [Pay API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation).

### Question:

My goal is to have a "one click checkout" experience in a mobile app.

Is it possible to use PayPal API to charge a customer directly from the server without redirecting the user to PayPal's express checkout confirmation page? The point is to let the user authorize the app only one time and not every time he buys something (and maybe get an authorization token in a similar fashion to Facebook API).

I was thinking of creating a fake recurring payment and "capture" the amount on each transaction, but I'm not sure how to do that and whether it'll achieve my goal.

If this is possible, it'll probably require some form of verification to the business. Where can I find information about this verification process.

Thank you so much for your time!

P.S. I've posted this question on x.com forums, but didn't get replies there.

Comment: I see a major security risk here. I Wouldn't see this happening at any point.

Comment: Well, if you can make charges without authorization by the user, you could theoretically have a scam where you constantly charge the user's paypal account for anything you want.

Comment: In theory you could, but the same is true with credit card information. Obviously, if you don't trust the business, you won't allow that. A security risk would be if someone else can capture the pre-approval key and use it, but I don't think that's the case. Also, PayPAl imposes a max amount and date limits on pre-approved transactions.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called Reference Transactions.  This will allow you to do one-click payments or store and bill a user's PayPal account like a credit card, without redirecting to PayPal; however, you *will* have to initially redirect the customer to PayPal the first time in order to get the customer's consent for this.

You also need approval from PayPal to use Reference Transactions, so not all merchants will be able to utilize this feature.

https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/recurring-payments-reference-transactions-and-preapproved-payments

https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppintegrationsnate/express-checkout-reference-transactions

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it using AJAX and webservice combunation and display conformation on same page

Comment: I'd like to communicate with PayPal from my server, not from the client. I don't want the user to see a paypal confirmation page except one time when the user authorized the app to make charges

Comment: From your server you can use CURL(if you are using php) to send card details from your server to paypal server. Once you get confirmation from paypal. transfer the client to confirmation page. To keep client waiting till the transaction has confirmed use Ajax